# Grouping objects after loop in Manim

Tags: python, for-loop, manim

Let's suppose I need to draw several objects evenly spaced along a line. I use a for-cycle for this.

```
    for number in range(-90, 90, 10):
        object = object.copy()
        object.move_to(np.array([number, 0, 0]))
```

I want group them after the cycle using VGroup.

```
        objects = VGroup(object)
        self.play(ShowCreation(objects))
```

Unsurprisingly, my code drawing only the last of the objects.
How to access the indices of all objects to draw them correctly?
I am new to Python and struggling with indexing.

Comment: `object` is a single object. You probably want to create a `list` and add each object into that list first

Comment: @UnholySheep You're right! But VGroup only works with Mobject: Exception: All submobjects must be of type VMobject.

Comment: There is an example in the official documentation where they create an array and then create the `VGroup` using the "star operator" on the list. https://azarzadavila-manim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/animation.html#showincreasingsubsets

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you very much! I adjusted this code and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code, if someone is interested.
Basically, it draws a grid-like image of Earth given a condition from xls-file.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

        workbook = load_workbook('name.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('sheetname')
        earth = []
        for row_cells in worksheet.iter_rows():
            for cell in row_cells:
                 if cell.value == 1:
                     lat = cell.row - 73
                     lon = cell.column - 109
                     rect = Rectangle(height=1, width=1, stroke_width=7, color=BACKGROUND)
                     rect.set_fill(GREEN_B, opacity=1)
                     rect.move_to(np.array([lon, lat, 0]))
                     earth.append(rect)
                 else:
                     pass

        group_earth = VGroup(*earth)
        self.play(FadeIn(group_earth), run_time=3)
        self.wait(2)
```